# How to define the operator= for a unique_ptr wrapper class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am trying to create a wrapper class for the std::unique_ptr, for now it just needs to support the basic operations for the unique_ptr, but in the future this would have more functionalities.

```
template<typename T>
class Unique {
public:
    Unique(std::nullptr_t) { pointer = nullptr; }
    template<typename ...Args>
    Unique(Args&&... args) { pointer = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

    T operator*() const { return *pointer.get(); }
    T* operator->() const { return pointer.get(); }

    // operator=() ?
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> pointer;
};
```

Doing `Unique<Foo> foo()` works just fine, but the problem happens when I try to do `Unique<Foo> bar = foo`, a compiler error happens saying

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo(Unique\<Foo\>&)’ { return unique\_ptr<\_Tp>(new \_Tp(std::forward<\_Args>(\_\_args)...)); }
```

How can I define a `operator=` to make this work?

Comment: You may want to look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D

Comment: @littleadv Ok, I should have explained better but the situation is like this: I have a base virtual class with a static method unique_ptr<Parent> Create() not defined, the user of the library is suppose to inherit this class and define Create() like { return make_unique<Child>(); }, and this return is put to a variable, because of that I need a operator= (btw this works when using the unique_ptr as I described) [Project here for context](https://github.com/pedrolmcastro/feather)

Comment: Not sure I understand, but it sounds like you need a template? Maybe show what you actually tried?

Comment: `operator*` should return `T&` btw

Comment: Unique<Foo> bar = foo; It's copy constructor or move copy constructor, instead of operator=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, as @che.wang pointed out, I actually needed a **Converting Assignment Constructor** based on (2) from the [unique_ptr reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) like:

`template<typename U> Unique(Unique<U>&& other) { pointer = std::move(other.pointer); }`

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of unique_ptr is that it is unique -- there can only be one pointer to an object and that pointer can't be copied.

If you want your class that contains a unique_ptr to be copied, you probably want it to create a new unique_ptr to a copy of the pointed at object:

```
template<typename T> Unique<T> &Unique<T>::operator=(const Unique<T> &a) {
    if (a.pointer)
        pointer = std::make_unique<T>(*a.pointer);
    else
        pointer.reset();
    return *this;
}
```

This will only work if T is not a dynamic class -- if T is actually a base class and you generally have pointers to a subblass, this won't work and will slice the object (which is bad).  You might be able to make something work if your dynamic base class has a clone method or something similar.

You might also want a move-assignment operator:

```
template<typename T> Unique<T> &Unique<T>::operator=(Unique<T> &&a) {
    pointer = std::move(a.pointer);
    return *this;
}
```

or you could put

```
Unique<T> &operator=(Unique<T> &&) = default;
```

in the class to get the compiler to create a default one for you (which would be the same as this unless there are other fields).

Comment: I am looking for this move-assignment operator, but I copied what you wrote and still did not compile, this needs to be defined outside or inside the class?

Comment: It needs to be declared in the class (as all methods need to be).  It can be defined either inside or outside the class (again, as with all methods -- there's nothing special about it).

Comment: So it is not working, I literally copied your code and the same error happend, could this be because of inheritance (I am returning a Unique<Child> to a Unique<Parent>)?

Comment: `Unique<Child>` and `Unique<Parent>` are unrelated classes that are not intercoinvertable.  You could create conversion functions that allow it (as std::unique_ptr does) but it is non-trvial (you need a templated ctor in the class)

Comment: I tested your code also with the exat same class and did not work either